# Window print function does not retain selected values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `select` tag and a print function. The problem is:: **the print method does not retain the selected values**. For example when I select option 1  and click `Print It` button, the page gets printed with the original `select` option

Here is my full code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdf5cajp/3/) . Why is it not printing the selected values?

Comment: Use CSS Print Media.... there is zero reason to open up a new window.

Comment: if you want to keep using JS, then try changing to  newWin.document.body.innerHTML =  tabToPrint.outerHTML;

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: If you open a new window, you need to reset all the values to what has been selected. You need a way of passing that on to the new window and setting them with JS. Or in your case, you need to modify the HTML you write to the window.

Comment: @putvande thank you. that's what i thought. Maybe i can reset the `selected` attribute before the print function starts?  
Maybe I can reset selected attribute when the onchange happens. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work –

Comment: Does this work for you https://jsfiddle.net/putvande/jdf5cajp/9/ ?

Comment: Yes it works :) Please post it as an answer so i can accept it. also  maybe it could help someone else.  THANKYOU